# Adobe Acrobat X Pro 10.1.4 always restarts. Ideas?

Tags: adobe, acrobat

I'm using Adobe Acrobat X Pro 10.1.4 on my Mac with MacOS 10.8 (12A269). I've got an active Adobe Creative Cloud subscription. All Adobe programs, I used so far, work great and activated themselves. Just Acrobat Pro always asks me to accept the license agreement. When I accept it, I can use Acrobat for some seconds, until it closes and asks again. Any ideas?

Comment: This should be migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: OK, when I start it using sudo, I can work with it after accepting. When next starting via UI, it asks again. Will try to reinstall, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seemd that the access rights were messed up as Buggabill suggested. A reinstall of Acrobat fixed this. That was quite strange, as it was a fresh installation before.